# Event handlers are not selectable in my Visual Studio 2010 installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have Visual Studio 2010. I learned that for creating event handlers we have to go to the code-behind page and then we have to select the event from the drop down list, but I am not able to select events other than page load.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screen prints/existing code would help...

But in the meantime, showing all event handlers appears to be a VB only feature.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053186/visual-studio-2010-showing-available-events-from-code-behind).  Could it be that you have not yet defined objects for those event handlers to act on?

Alternatively, it may just be a C# thing.  You may view events available to particular controls in the object's Properties window in the Form layout view.