# It is possible to setup Visual Studio 2010 to list only methods in navigation bar?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In the bar are listed methods and properties together and would be better for me to show only methods for quick navigation through class

[image: Navigation Bar]

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053186/visual-studio-2010-showing-available-events-from-code-behind

Comment: spajce: in your link is not answer for my question

Comment: yes, but this your question is possible duplicate `:D` http://stackoverflow.com/a/5053283/1080742

Comment: your linked question is about generating events by navigation bar, i need to filter items in bar to show only methods

Comment: @fanosek Have you got any solution for this question?